# Syntax error when trying to display a local image in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to display an image in my notebook such as,

```
![title](img/x.png)
```

When I Change cell type to markdown it works but displays this

[image]

Comment: change your cell type to markdown?

Comment: Thanks I changed to markdown but it displays a broken image? @QuangHoang

Comment: Works on my settings. Check if there is `img/x.png` in the folder containing the notebook file.

Comment: https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Working%20With%20Markdown%20Cells.html#Local-files the image needs to be in your notebook directory: `<img src="x.png"/>`

Answer (score 1):

Here is some diagnostics you can make using Python itself

```
import os
filename = 'img/x.png'
print(os.path.abspath(filename))
```

Does this command print the expected path? If not, fix filename accordingly.

```
print(os.path.exists(filename))
```

Is this "True"? If not, check that the file exists.

For the following test you need OpenCV. If you don't have it, you need to install `opencv-python`, e.g. using `pip install opencv-python`.

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread(filename)
print(im.shape)
```

This should print a tuple with elements image height, image width and number of channels (for a color image). If it doesn't, the image is most probably corrupted.

You can also display the image using matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()
```

If you see wrong colors, probably matplotlib displays it uses a wrong palette or wrong channel order (RGB instead of BGR ets.) Take a look at `plt.imshow` help to find, how to fix it.